# UIButton do not respond to touch event

Tags: ios, uibutton, event-handling, responder-chain

I have a UIButton not responding to touch event. And the button only has some subviews not handling events. So I replaced it with my customized UIButton to find out what happened. Below is my code:

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton

@end

@implementation CustomButton

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return [super beginTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
}
@end
```

I found out that the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method was called, but the `beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:` was never called. It seems that the event has been dispatched to my button, but I don't understand why the event has never been tracked. Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: *I found out that the touchesBegan:withEvent: method was called, but the touchesBegan:withEvent: was never called.*--Which is it?

Comment: @7stud Sorry, I’ve fixed my typo.  : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable user interaction of views that are above the button which are not listening for events. Check that the button has user interaction enabled. Check the frame size of `UIButton` and ensure that it is not zero specifically when using auto layout programatically.

Comment: Disable user interaction of views that are above the button fix my problem.  But one thing confused me is that the subview is forwarding touch event to button, but why it is not recognized? I experimented the hitTest method, and find out that if you disable the above view, the hitTest view will be the button, if not it will be the above view. It seems to be the difference. Even though the hitTest view is not the button, as the default behavior of UIView and responder chain, the event will be forwarded to the button properly. touch methods of the button was called may prove all this.

Comment: In a word, my problem is why the UIButton doesn’t track touch event  forwarded to it by its subview? It is designated to be like this, or a bug?